# Why am I always getting a segmentation fault in this CS50 Pset?

Tags: c, cs50

I am currently attempting Pset2 of CS50 and in `caesar.c`, the user is supposed to enter k through argv; if he doesn't I am supposed to "yell"
at the user telling him to use command line  arguments. But if I try the following I ALWAYS get a segmentation fault.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const string argv[])
{
    unsigned int k = atoi(argv[1]);

    if(k == NULL)
    {
        printf("YOU DID NOT INPUT ANYTHING AS COMMAND LINE ARGUMENT! ");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
unsigned int k = atoi(argv[1]);
```

`argv[1]` might be `NULL`. You should check it before calling `atoi` because passing `NULL` to `atoi` results in Undefined Behavior. Change

```
if(k == NULL)
{
printf("YOU DID NOT INPUT ANYTHING AS COMMAND LINE ARGUMENT! ");
return 1;
}
```

to

```
if(argv[1] == NULL)
{
    printf("YOU DID NOT INPUT ANYTHING AS COMMAND LINE ARGUMENT! ");
    return 1;
}
```

or

```
if(argc < 2)
{
    printf("YOU DID NOT INPUT ANYTHING AS COMMAND LINE ARGUMENT! ");
    return 1;
}
```

and move it before

```
unsigned int k = atoi(argv[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check for `argc` before accessing `argv`, because without arguments , the argv doesn't have anything initialized at `argv[1]`, which is causing the segfault, because you're accessing uninitialized memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use `argc` to check count.

Check following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    if( argc < 2) {
        printf("YOU DID NOT INPUT ANYTHING AS COMMAND LINE ARGUMENT! \n");
        return -1;
    }

    if(strcmp(argv[1],"k") == 0) { // yes, key is inputed,
        // ...
        printf("ok\n");
    } else { // it's not k,
        // ...
        printf("Not ok.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```